# Conversion of data frame to matrix : error

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I want to use `rowttests` function from package:genefilter. The `rowtests` function arguments are :

```
>rowttests(x, fac)

x: Numeric matrix. The matrix must not contain ‘NA’ values.  For
      ‘rowttests’ and ‘colttests’, ‘x’ can also be an
      ‘ExpressionSet’.
fac: Factor which codes the grouping to be tested.
```

So, My input is dataframe below, and i perform the following steps but got error ..

```
> dataframe
V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  5  6  7
2  2  6  7  8
3  3  7  8  9
4  4  8  9 10
5  5  9 10 11
6  6 10 11 12
7  7 11 12 13

>mat <-as.matrix(dataframe)
> mat
 V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  1  5  6  7
[2,]  2  6  7  8
[3,]  3  7  8  9
[4,]  4  8  9 10
[5,]  5  9 10 11
[6,]  6 10 11 12
[7,]  7 11 12 13

>fac <- factor(c(1,1,2,2))
```

The error is :

```
rowttests(mat, fac)
Error in rowcoltt(x, fac, tstatOnly, 1L) :
Invalid argument 'x': must be a real matrix.


> mode(mat)
[1] "numeric"

> class(mat)
[1] "matrix"
```

I also tried:

```
>mat1 <-matrix((stack(dataframe))[[1]],nrow=7, ncol=4)
>mat1
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    6    7
[2,]    2    6    7    8
[3,]    3    7    8    9
[4,]    4    8    9   10
[5,]    5    9   10   11
[6,]    6   10   11   12
[7,]    7   11   12   13
```

again same error

```
rowttests(mat1, fac)
Error in rowcoltt(x, fac, tstatOnly, 1L)
Invalid argument 'x': must be a real matrix.
```

Could anybody tell me how I can convert data frame to matrix so that I can use it in rowttests function?

Comment: After poking around a bit, this IMHO is a bit of sloppy argument checking/passing on the part of the package author. What's happening here is that your matrix is being passed to some C code as integers, and then the C code is insisting on "reals", and the test fails. This is unrelated to whether you start with a df or a matrix. AFAICT the function is just broken on integer matrices, and it smells like a bug. I might consider contacting the package author.

Comment: For instance, try running `is.real` and `is.integer` on your `mat` above.